# How do you use Beamer with Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Error "expected a value of type 'Widget' but got one of type '_Future<BeamPage'".
I'm trying to pass the 'cool' RentalAd object below to the next screen...

```
routes: {
...
 '/advert/:id': (context, state, data) async {
 final String? propertyId = state.pathParameters['id'];
    final RentalAd cool = await FirebaseFirestore.instance // cool from here
 .collection(kTestRentalAds)
        .doc(propertyId)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) => RentalAd.fromFirestore(doc));
    return BeamPage(
      key: ValueKey('adverts-$propertyId'),
 title: 'Advert',
 child: SearchHouseDetailsPage(house: cool), // cool to here
 );
 }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. The solution is to simply pass the propertyId to the next page. On the next page you use a FutureBuilder, scroll down to 'One-time Read' on this documentation page https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/